# Tap here to sign in to network

Tags: wi-fi, captive-portal

```
Asus ROG 2 Phone
17.0240.2009.49
Not Rooted
Happens All the time
Wifi Connection in my home
```

---

Ever since updating to 17.0240.2009.49, my phone has been listing one of my wifi connections as "Limited"

But today, it now prompts to "Sign in to Wi-Fi network"

I have no captive portal on this network.

My laptop (windows 10 pro) connects without any problems or prompt.

My tablet (Nexus 9) connects without any problems or prompt.

If I tap to sign in, I am shown a blank page.

If I select "Use this network as-is" in the 3 dots menu, it works for a few minutes and then puts an X on the Wifi Icon saying "no connection" - even though I was browsing web pages before then.

After that, I can't access anything.

I have tried:

```
static/dhcp - no change
Treat as Unmetered - no change
Rebooted - no change
Reset Wifi - no change
Dynamic/Static Mac address - no change
Rebooted the router - no change
looked through pfSense logs - no information
```

Any ideas?

---

Update:

After selecting "Use this network as-is", it shows connected for a bit, then shows disconnected with an X in the Wifi Icon. At that point, I can't access anything.

But after waiting a few minutes, I can access everything just fine again - even though it still shows an X on the Wifi Icon and says 'No Internet' when I pull down the status bar. However, that is only with Mobile Network Data turned OFF or I turn off "Switch to Mobile data when WiFi has no Internet"

So, for some stupid reason, the phone thinks I have no Internet on this Wifi SSID, so it tries over Network Data and fails - so nothing works.

There must be a Ping Test or something for Wifi that is failing and so it reports no Internet and borks everything up.

What the HECK is going on and how do I get this back to a sensible state?

Comment: You should state which versions of Android (8, 9, 10, etc) the devices are running and if the Nexus 9 tablet is running a custom ROM.

Comment: Already posted Asus ROG 2 Phone 17.0240.2009.49 (its Android 10, duh)
Nexus 9 has last official Android update: 7.1.1

Comment: And I assume you've cleared the WiFi access point, turned off the phone, restarted the phone and tried to sign into the WiFi and still gives you the captive portal message.

Comment: yes: reset wifi on the phone, forgot the wifi access point, rebooted, reconnected and re-entered wifi password and it still gives the captive portal message.

Comment: One thing to try is to check the `adb logcat` logs and see if anything in particular comes up when you try to access your WiFi access point. You'll need to enable developer mode, https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options, and see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12658349/295004

Comment: I got a dump. It's huge. I have no idea what I'm looking for. All the statuslabels=No internet for that Wifi.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113812/discussion-between-morrison-chang-and-da-hai-zhu).

Answer (score 0):

After dicking around in ADB with Captive Portal setting, changing URLs and crap, I finally just gave up and set :

```
adb shell settings put global captive_portal_mode 0
```

now it doesn't check, doesn't prompt to login to a non-existent portal, or show "No Internet" on the wifi - and the wifi does work.

Don't know WTF was going on, but I wasted an entire day screwing around with this stupid phone.